# Magento2 - Display lowest price from other customer groups

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

So, right now. Magento 2 CE Tiered Pricing will show you that you are getting a discounted price if your group is configured for a discount on the product's advanced pricing configuration.

How would I show the group with the biggest discount price to customers that do not have a discount tier configured for their group?

I'd rather develop this myself but am unsure how to exactly do. If there's an extension that accomplishes this I'll take it but if there's info on how I can achieve this I'd rather take that route.

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no Magento 2 inbuilt feature for this. Even in Magento EE. I'm working on it.

Best way is you should implement a way or find a module for this.

Comment: That's what I also asked for advice for in my question:

"I'd rather develop this myself but am unsure how to exactly do. If there's an extension that accomplishes this I'll take it but if there's info on how I can achieve this I'd rather take that route."